# Writing data from tableview to excel using swift

Tags: swift, cocoa

Code to export the data present in the TableView to the excel.
Code to be written in Swift.

Any help will be great.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://github.com/renebigot/XlsxReaderWriter

You cannot create a excel sheet with the library, but you can modify an existing empty excel sheet with the data.